# Create own "toolbox" or "toolset" in QGIS and move tools to that toolset

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In ArcGIS Tools are located in "toolsets" wich are located in "toolboxes". One can create a new Toolbox and toolset and copy Tools from other toolsets into to the new toolset.

Is there a way to do the same in QGIS? To create a new "Provider" and copy Tools into that Provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the moment but a feature request has been sent about creating a "Favourites" section where users could manually add their frequently-used tools:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29220